# Task `IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup` encounter issue "The Parameter is incorrect .. exited with code '87'"

Tags: .net-core, iis, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

hoping that someone can help me with my issue. I've been trying to solve this issue for a week now and still doesn't have a solution.

Here is my issue - I'm encountering the below issue when my pipeline is publishing my application in IIS (`Local IIS`)

[image]

Before, it's working fine and I don't know why this happen now after re-running a new pipeline. I tried to re-install my IIS and removed all `MachineKeys`. But still got the same error. Also, after re-installing everything, I changed the `Owner` of all `MachineKeys` installed on my machine to my account (`which is an administrator`).

Also, I tried to removed this in the `applicationHost.config` of the `inetsrv` as other solution I found on the internet suggestion but still got the same issue.

[image]

But then, after searching for other solution - I found out that the command that's running on my pipeline for publishing into `IIS` somehow causes this issue. The `password` parameter.

I tried the command below, on running `cmd` as `Administrator` and removing the `password` parameter and it works.

```
appcmd.exe set site /site.name:"RTP_LoginService" -applicationDefaults.applicationPool:"RTP_LoginServiceAppPool" -[path='/'].[path='/'].physicalPath:"%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot\RTP_LoginService" -[path='/'].[path='/'].userName: -[path='/'].[path='/'].password:
```

But still  thinking why this become an issue right now as before it's working even though there's a `password` parameter and I don't have any changes on the `Task` for publishing in my local `IIS` as this is a default command by the `Task`.

Thanks you in advance to anyone who can help me and give light to my issue I'm experiencing.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 0):

Giving `Credentials of Physical Path` for `Virtual Machine Directory` can also be the trouble for this password excluding issue. Tried to reproduce the issue and got some solution for this as mentioned below.

This problem will also rise because of the **corrupted** `IIS Configuration Key`. We need to avoid the key to be corrupted by **encrypting** the key in **applicationhost.config** file.

1. Create another test machine and generate configuration key.
2. Use that key for checking.

**Exporting the key**

- From the working IIS server we need to export the key.

  **aspnet_regiis -px "iisConfigurationKey" "Your path for file.xml" -pri**
- Import config file from created test server

  **aspnet_regiis -pi "iisConfigurationKey" "Your path for file.xml"**
- Implement **AES encryption algorithm**: Replace the `AES Provider` which is a default encryption method element from **applicationHost.config** and **configProtectedData** and restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working now. So, I fixed this issue by re-installing `IIS URL Rewrite` as somehow it got uninstalled on my machine. After that, it now working as expected.